# Honolulu to Mainland. Do I need to show my passport/visa again?

Tags: visas, air-travel, domestic-travel, hawaii, us-visa

Honolulu is my port of entry. Went outside to explore the island overnight. Now I need go to the mainland (san francisco) which I have the ticket and boarding pass already.

Do I need to go again to immgration since it’s going to mainland?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Hawaii has been a state of the United States since August 21, 1959. I am not well versed enough in the laws of the era to know whether you needed a passport before but for sure you didn't since that, now almost sixty years. Official [source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/980/~/needing-a-passport-to-enter-the-united-states-from-u.s.-territories) has this to say:

> Hawaii is a U.S. state and therefore passport documentation requirements for U.S. citizens and LPR's do not apply.

You will need some [TSA approved identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) and REAL ID will change the list next year, nonetheless the statement will be true: a TSA approved id is both necessary and enough to fly within the United States.

Comment: This is correct for most of the cases. E.g. direct flight on a US airline. But for operative reasons you may get to go to an "international flight". e.g. stop on Canada, or from an airlines which use the 8th freedom (e.g. Japan -> Honoloulu -> Los Angeles)